# How many ring homomorphisms are there between the ring $\Bbb Z_4$ into the ring $\Bbb Z_6$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-writing

How many ring homomorphisms are there between the ring $\Bbb Z_4$ into the ring $\Bbb Z_6$ ?

My solution goes like this:

Let $\phi:\Bbb Z_4\to \Bbb Z_6$ be a ring homomorphism.

We note $\Bbb Z_4=\{0_4,1_4,2_4,3_4\}$ and $\Bbb Z_6=\{0_6,1_6,2_6,3_6,4_6,5_6\}.$

We observe that, $$\phi(1_4)=\phi(1_4.1_4)=\phi(1_4)^2\implies \phi(1_4)^2-\phi(1_4)=0_6\implies \phi(1_4)[\phi(1_4)-1_6)=0.$$

But this is possible if :

- $\phi(1_4)=0_6$
- $\phi(1_4)-1_6=0$
- $\phi(1_4)=2_6,\phi(1_4)-1_6=3_6$
- $\phi(1_4)=3_6,\phi(1_4)-1_6=2_6$

So, if $\phi(1_6)=0_6$ then $\phi$ is a trivial homomorphism.

If $\phi(1_4)=1_6$ then, $\phi(3_4)=3_6$ and $\phi(2_4)=2_6.$ But, $$\phi(3_4+2_4)=\phi(1_4)=1_6\neq \phi(3_4)+\phi(2_4)=3_6+2_6=5_6$$ and hence, $\phi$ is not a homomorphism so, $\phi(1_4)\neq 1_6.$

Again, $\phi(1_4)=2_6,\phi(1_4)-1_6=3_6$ is not possible as $\phi(1_4)=2_6=4_6,$ is absurd.

If $\phi(1_4)=3_6,\phi(1_4)-1_6=2_6$ then, $\phi(1_4)=3_6.$ But this means, $$\phi(2_4)=\phi(1_4)+\phi(1_4)=0_6=\phi(0_4)$$ and $\phi(3_4)=3_6.$ Thus, $\phi(x_4)=3x_6$ is a homomorphism.

All the cases are exhausted and thus we can conclude that the only homomorphisms that exists between the ring $\Bbb Z_4$ into the ring $\Bbb Z_6$ are the trivial homomorphism and $\phi(x_4)=x_6,\forall x_4\in\Bbb Z_4.$

---

Is the above solution correct? Can any improvements be made to the solution to improve the readability and clarity of the solution? I want to know whether the way I have presented the proof is valid. All in all, I am asking can any improvements be made in the proof writing of the solution above.

Comment: Does your definition of a ring homomorphism not require that 1 is mapped to 1?

Comment: @Karl Well no, my definition of homomorphism between rwo rings is: Let $R$ and $R'$ be 2 rings. A mapping $\phi:R\to R'$ is called a homomorphism if $\phi(a+b)=\phi(a)+\phi(b)$ and $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b),\forall a,b\in R.$

Comment: Ok. You can take a more systematic approach to this question by noticing that the elements of $\Bbb Z_4$ are $1,1+1,1+1+1,1+1+1+1$, so the homomorphism is completely determined by where it sends $1$. In particular, look at $\phi(1+1+1+1)$. I think you made a mistake in ruling out the $\phi(1)=3$ case.

Comment: @Karl I am not sure, but $\phi(1_4)=3_6$ looks impossible as then, $\phi$ is not even a homomorphism as I demonstrated in OP.

Comment: In that line, how did you get $\phi(3_4)+\phi(2_4)=3_6+2_6$?

Comment: @Karl  There was a mistake with $\phi(2_4)$. It will be $\phi(2_4)=0_6$ and again we get a contradiction as $\phi$ does not remain $1-1$ for $\phi(0_4)=0_6$. The calculation for $\phi(2_6), \phi(3_6)$ is as follows: We have, $\phi(1_4)=3_6$ and so, $$\phi(3_4)=\phi(1_4+1_4+1_4)=\phi(1_4)+\phi(1_4)+\phi(1_4)=3_6+3_6+3_6=9_6=3_6$$ and similarly, $$\phi(2_4)=\phi(1_4+1_4)=\phi(1_4)+\phi(1_4)=0_6$$

Comment: Thinking 'categorically': maps $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ are the same things as maps $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ which kill $4\Bbb Z$ which are the same things as elements of $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ which are killed by $4$.

Comment: I agree with your corrected computation of $\phi(3)$ and $\phi(2)$, but where's the contradiction?

Comment: @Karl You are correct. There is no contradiction. I have edited my original post. Is the solution correct now?

Comment: This site is not really geared toward polishing everyone's individual solutions to a problem.  The question being asked is a very frequently asked one with lots of good answers already. If they are deficient somehow let us know.

Comment: You probably have an instructor, yes?  If so, delegating your discussions you should be having with the instructor to random people on the internet is really doing a disservice to both of you!  Discussions with your instructor on topics like this are (supposed to be) an ideal use of that relationship.

Comment: @rschwieb No I don't have an instructor. Thanks for all the links you attached. Just one last question: Do you feel that my solution is valid?